# Handling Errors for Multiple T-tests when using Tidy and Do

Tags: r, try-catch, tidyverse, tidyr, t-test

I've been using functions `do` and `tidy` to perform multiple t-tests on a data frame that has been group by categories ahead of time. However some of the values in the data frame are constant and I usually have to filter these out for the test to work since it returns `Error in t.test.default(.$y) : data are essentially constant`. I’m looking for a way to perfor the t-test using do and tidy as normal but instead of filtering our the categories that are constant have estimate column use the value of that category and the others be NA.

Example Dataframe:

```
trial<-data.frame(
  type=rep(c("A","B","C"),times=2,length.out=10),
  y=c(1,2,3,1,3,2,1,2,3,1)
)
```

Data frame:

```
   type y
1     A 1
2     B 2
3     C 3
4     A 1
5     B 3
6     C 2
7     A 1
8     B 2
9     C 3
10    A 1
```

Filtered T-test:

```
trial.ttest<-trial %>% 
  group_by(type) %>% 
  filter(!type=="A") %>% 
  do(tidy(t.test(.$y))))
```

Filtered T-test Results:

```
  type estimate statistic    p.value parameter  conf.low
1    B 2.333333         7 0.01980394         2 0.8991158
2    C 2.666667         8 0.01526807         2 1.2324491
  conf.high            method alternative
1  3.767551 One Sample t-test   two.sided
2  4.100884 One Sample t-test   two.sided
```

I’ve tried using the following code which uses `trycatch` and `tribble` to do this but I end up with the `Error: C stack usage  15923504 is too close to the limit` as a error.

```
trial.ttest<-trial %>% 
  group_by(type) %>% 
  do(tidy(tryCatch(t.test(.$y),error=function(e){
    tribble(
      ~estimate,
      .$y,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
    )
  })))
```

If I forgo using `tribble` and just have `tryCatch` return the value it adds it in a new column named `x`.

Code:

```
trial.ttest<-trial %>% 
  group_by(type) %>% 
  do(tidy(tryCatch(t.test(.$y),error=function(e){
    .$y
  })))
```

Results:

```
  type  x estimate statistic    p.value parameter  conf.low
1    A  1       NA        NA         NA        NA        NA
2    A  1       NA        NA         NA        NA        NA
3    A  1       NA        NA         NA        NA        NA
4    A  1       NA        NA         NA        NA        NA
5    B NA 2.333333         7 0.01980394         2 0.8991158
6    C NA 2.666667         8 0.01526807         2 1.2324491
  conf.high            method alternative
1        NA              <NA>        <NA>
2        NA              <NA>        <NA>
3        NA              <NA>        <NA>
4        NA              <NA>        <NA>
5  3.767551 One Sample t-test   two.sided
6  4.100884 One Sample t-test   two.sided
```

Is there a way to have the constant values go into the estimate column, with the method column resulting in `Constant Value` and all others being `NA` instead of a new column as in the last bit of code?

**EDIT 1:**

I forgot to add the desired resulting data frame.

Desired Result:

```
  type estimate statistic    p.value parameter  conf.low conf.high            method alternative
1    A 1.000000        NA         NA        NA        NA        NA    Constant Value        <NA>
2    B 2.333333         7 0.01980394         2 0.8991158  3.767551 One Sample t-test   two.sided
3    C 2.666667         8 0.01526807         2 1.2324491  4.100884 One Sample t-test   two.sided
```

**Edit 2: Solution Attempt A**

Code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(broom)
trial %>% 
  split(.$type) %>% 
  map_if(.p = ~length(unique(.$y))>1, 
         .f = ~tidy(t.test(.$y)), 
         .else = ~tibble(estimate=.$y[1], method="Constant Value")) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = 'type')
```

Result:

```
  type type  y estimate statistic    p.value parameter  conf.low
1    A    A  1       NA        NA         NA        NA        NA
2    A    A  1       NA        NA         NA        NA        NA
3    A    A  1       NA        NA         NA        NA        NA
4    A    A  1       NA        NA         NA        NA        NA
5    B <NA> NA 2.333333         7 0.01980394         2 0.8991158
6    C <NA> NA 2.666667         8 0.01526807         2 1.2324491
  conf.high            method alternative
1        NA              <NA>        <NA>
2        NA              <NA>        <NA>
3        NA              <NA>        <NA>
4        NA              <NA>        <NA>
5  3.767551 One Sample t-test   two.sided
6  4.100884 One Sample t-test   two.sided
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option using `purrr::map_if`, we apply *t.test* only if `length(unique(y))>1` or `n_distinct(y)>1`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(broom)
trial %>% 
  split(.$type) %>% 
  map_if(.p = ~length(unique(.$y))>1, 
         .f = ~tidy(t.test(.$y)), 
         .else = ~tibble(estimate=.$y[1], method="Constant Value")) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = 'type')

# A tibble: 3 x 9
  type  estimate method            statistic p.value parameter conf.low conf.high alternative
  <chr>    <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>      
1 A         1    Constant Value          NA  NA             NA   NA         NA    NA         
2 B         2.33 One Sample t-test        7.  0.0198         2    0.899      3.77 two.sided  
3 C         2.67 One Sample t-test        8   0.0153         2    1.23       4.10 two.sided
```

PS: Using `purrr` >= 0.3.2

Comment: I didn’t point out the desired result as code. My mistake, I apologize. I was looking for something along the lines of what I added above. I tried using the same approach with a new line between `map_if' and 'bind_rows` that would coerce the A `split` using to a `tibble` with the same column names but that did not work `tribble(
    ~estimate, ~statistic, ~p.value, ~conf.low, ~conf.high, ~method,~alternative,
          .$y,         NA,       NA,        NA,         NA,"Constant Value",NA
  )`.

Comment: It's okay, please check my update. We can use `map_if`'s argument _.else_ to pass the required dataframe.

Comment: I tried running the code and I still got more or less the same result. the column names seems to be the only diffrence in the column names. I looked into using `.else`  within 
 `map_if` and as you said it should work but. I'm not sure why it isn't. I tried only loading the 3 libraries that we'de use for this code and I still got the same result. I added the resulting `df` under Edit 2 since it's too long for the commetnts.

Comment: I was finally able to get the your solution to work. I had to do install `purrr` to version `0.3.2` and remove `0.2.5`. then the code worked as intended. Thank you for your help with this.